# Distorted audio on Ubuntu after installing sg3-utils and using it to connect an Apple Superdrive

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I was trying to make Apple's SuperDrive work on Ubuntu, and followed [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/AnnoyingTechnology/dbaae864822cf08372f0aafe64a63477) to do so:

```
sudo apt install sg3-utils -y
sudo sg_raw /dev/sr0 EA 00 00 00 00 00 01
```

It worked, since I was able to read the information from the DVD. However, it broke the audio. Now as soon as I start playing something, I have audio but I can only hear it for a few seconds and it sounds very distorted. It also changes volume on its own for the few seconds that it plays, then finally mutes itself, although the system/app volume is unchanged.  I've tried playing music from audio files, playing a video on VLC, playing a video on Firefox/youtube, all with the same problem. System sounds like changing volume also makes a distorted sound, and also stops making sound after a few seconds if I keep trying to use it, but if I wait a few seconds and use it again, it works.

I tried removing sg3-utils with:

```
sudo apt-get remove sg3-utils
```

but nothing changed. I also saw several posts explaining to do an update/upgrade/clean, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get udpate
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

with no changes. Also tried doing what it's explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/508234/738196), also in [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1217467/738196), and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138964/738196), and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164056/738196), and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1115356/738196), although I'm not entirely sure I did what I was supposed to do in the last one.

I have an Asus ZenBook (UX433F) laptop, with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa). The sound in Windows is working fine with no issues.

Any ideas on what could be wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was an issue with Windows. Going to Windows and shuting down instead of restarting fixed the problem, as suggested [here](https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-asus-zenbook-15-ux534f-realtek-hd-audio-problem.27384/#post-94194).

I can now also go back to Windows, restart, come back to Ubuntu and the sound is fine. I did not have fast boot on (not on BIOS, not on Windows settings). My guess is the problem had nothing to do with the sg3-utils, and the issue arose when I plugged in the Apple Superdrive in Windows, then restarted the system instead of shuting down.